# Measuring how much battery charge a process uses in Windows

Tags: windows, process, battery-life

As battery life in most laptops is naturally limited to a few hours, is there any way to know how much battery a process (i.e. Microsoft Word or GNS.exe) is using? Like process A is using this much amount of battery... As far I know GDI32.dll in Win32 API is responsible for delivering display (icons, menu etc) on screen. Please help me as I want to take this topic as my case study.

Comment: I think the level of battery power consumption is proportional to processor time usage by specific process. Unless you are trying to crack MD5/NTLM hashes with GPU , otherwise there is no need to distinguish the battery usage and processor usage. Please explain the aim in detail.

Comment: @mnmnc Thanks for comment...
My aim is to make a application like process explorer...which will tell in depth info about process with battery consumption...this will help the user to have control over battery usage(i.e.is process A consumes more battery,he can kill a process to save some battery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct `process <-> battery life` relationship, the thing that uses battery life up (that could be associated with a process) are side effects of the process running. Here is a list of things that I could come up from the top of my head.

- **CPU** - The CPU is a constant draw of power in your system. Many laptops will slow/shut down parts of the CPU to save battery life but if a program has a high CPU % the processor will never be able to go in to that low power state
- **GPU** - The GPU is a bigger draw than the CPU but is not used most of the time. If the program has any kind of 3D it may increase the batter drain
- **Hard Disk access** - If you are using a spinning disk HDD it takes energy to spin up from idle that platter. If a program has a lot of I/O to the disk or causes the swap file to be read from a lot that can drain your battery.
- **DVD Drive access** - The DVD drive has motor just like the HDD and will spend energy just the same. It also has a low power laser that needs to be run which also contributes a small power draw.
- **Network Card** - The network card also takes a bit of power to function, if you're constantly downloading it can't go into low-power state either. (Thanks [Thomas](https://superuser.com/questions/524797/measuring-how-much-battery-charge-a-process-uses-in-windows/524810#comment632577_524810))

This list likely is missing some things that could contribute, but as I said, it came from the top of my head.

---

For the measuring aspect you can use [Windows Event Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to monitor all of the above items on my list on a per process basis and generate reports to find out what is using each reasource

Comment: I think the network card also takes a bit of power to function, if you're constantly downloading it can't go into low-power state either.

Comment: @Scott Thank You for your comment...
It was knowledgeable comment...sure ill try..if you get any info about this topic..please inform me...it would be helpful.